# Can not open .msg files

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, msg

I have about 90 .msg, outlook files that I need to open, convert the excel attachment to .csv files and save off.  Presently, the code below is to simply open the .msg outlook file, but the error appears :[image]

How can I permit the .msg files to be opened.

Script:

```
Sub OpenMSGRenameDownloadAttachement()

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim MsgCount As Integer

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Change the path given month, ie. do this for Jan, Feb, April
    inPath = "C:\January Messages"

    thisFile = LCase(Dir(inPath & "\*.msg"))
    Do While thisFile <> ""

        Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(thisFile)

        Msg.Display

        MsgBox Msg.Subject
        thisFile = Dir
    Loop

    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this is an obvious question, but is the file already open?  E.g. in Outlook? Or in Excel from a failed earlier attempt at your code?  Or in Excel from a previous successful attempt?  (It doesn't look like you are explicitly doing a `Close`, so it might still be open.)  Also, does this page apply: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2633737/the-openshareditem-method-for-outlook-holds-a-file-handle-on-signed-.msg-files

Comment: This is a one time thing. How can I rewrite this to work, at least to open the emails, I can take converting the excel from there.

Comment: You are using Dir wrong. Try `thisFile = Dir(inPath)` and after `Do While thisFile <> ""` put an If condition `If Right(thisFile, 3) = "msg" Then`,and you don't need to physically open messages to get attachments as far as I know.

Comment: @Tehscript can you post and answer with the full script out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub OpenMSGRenameDownloadAttachement()
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNs = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'objNs.Logon

inPath = "C:\January Messages\"
outPath = "C:\January Messages\attachments\" 'create this folder for attachments or use your own
thisFile = Dir(inPath & "*.msg")

Do While Len(thisFile) > 0
    Set Msg = objNs.OpenSharedItem(inPath & thisFile)
    'MsgBox inPath & thisFile
    'MsgBox Msg.Subject
    'MsgBox Msg.SenderEmailAddress
    'MsgBox Msg.Recipients.Item(1).Address
    For Each objAtt In Msg.Attachments
        If Right(objAtt, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(objAtt, 3) = "xls" Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile outPath & Split(objAtt.DisplayName, ".")(0) & ".csv"
        End If
    Next
    thisFile = Dir
Loop

Set objOL = Nothing
Set objNs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Debug.Print` to `Msgbox`

Comment: Define "This also does not work". What happens when it does not work?

Comment: I see the issue, I did not place a "\", in the path. This works now thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I edited the code to look for new(.xlsx) and old(.xls) excel file formats in the attachment and save them as .csv files. Also uncomment the relevant lines to get filepath, subject, sender email address and recipients email address.

Comment: Thank you, but it notes the file format and extension are unsafe when attempting to open in excel. Is this the best way to convert to CSV?

Comment: No the corrrect way to convert it to csv is `objAtt.SaveAs Filename:=outPath & Split(objAtt.DisplayName, ".")(0) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV` but Outlook object does not support `SaveAs` so this is a workaround. Another option is you can save it as it is `objAtt.SaveAsFile outPath & objAtt.DisplayName`, and then save workbook using the above-mentioned method.

Comment: FWIW - If you change `thisFile = Dir(inPath)` to `thisFile = Dir(inPath & "*.msg")` then you won't need to check the last three characters of the filename within the loop - `Dir` would only return filenames matching the wildcard specification.  It was the missing `inpath & ` in `OpenSharedItem(thisFile)` that was probably causing the OP's problem.  (`Dir(inPath)` is implicitly doing `Dir(inPath & "*.*")`)

Comment: @YowE3K That is so true, thank you for revealing this.

Comment: When I edit my answer to reflect these changes, my accepted answer and vote is gone. Still trying to get used to the dynamics of SO.